# Why does why C# code keep crashing Unity? (I'm a beginner to Unity and C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

Whenever I run my game it freezes, but it doesn't without this C# script.

I've tried changing around my code, and it works outside of Unity, in .NET (with some tweaks to certain functions) but when it's in Unity it crashes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Throw : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    string final = "final:";
    public float force = 1;
    public float accuracy = 0;

    void incto(float amount)
    {
        while (force < amount)
        {
            Debug.Log(force);
            force++;
        }
    }

    void decto(float amount)
    {
        while (force > amount)
        {
            Debug.Log(force);
            force--;
        }
    }

    void fstart()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            force = 1;
            incto(200);
            decto(1);
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {

                Debug.Log(final + force);
                break;

            }


        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        fstart();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(force);
    }
}
```

It should decrease and increase the force value, then stop when you press E, but Unity just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity takes care of the `while(true)` for you.  Unity's `while(true)` calls your `FixedUpdate`, you just need to fill it in.

Unity only captures keystrokes once per frame, so `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)` will always return the same value. Unity crashes because of your while(true) is an infinite loop.

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Answer (score 0):

i belive that unity starts catching key strokes after the first frame, not before, try moving fstart() behind a first run bool in the FixedUpdate function

oh and this will hang the entire program every time it executes a frame.....

Answer (score 0):

The code crashes because you have an infinite loop here:

```
    while (true)
    {

    }
```

It will never exit the loop so nothing more happens. Just put that code into Update() method, which gets called by the engine on every frame, it will do the trick